# generate_access_token() with subject for Google service account

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, gmail-api, google-iam

In python, I'm trying to call the GMail API via a service account with [Delegated domain-wide authority](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests), **without** using `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE`.

My objective is to avoid creating a secret `Key` for the service account. Instead, I gave the `Service Account Token Creator` role to the process owner (me in local dev, App Engine Service Account in prod).

In the code below I successfully get and use an access token for the service account, without any `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE`.

```py
from google.cloud.iam_credentials_v1 import IAMCredentialsClient
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
import googleapiclient.discovery

tk = IAMCredentialsClient().generate_access_token(
    name=f'projects/-/serviceAccounts/{service_id}',
    scope=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.insert'],
    # subject='admin@my.domain' doesn't work here :'(
)
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=Credentials(tk.access_token))
response = service.users().messages().insert(userId='user@my.domain', body=body).execute()
```

Problem is, after granting permissions to the service account in Google Admin of `my.domain`, I get the following error:

> {'message': 'Precondition check failed.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'failedPrecondition'}

I suspect that what I am missing is the `subject`, i.e. the email of an admin at `my.domain`.

I know I can provide the `subject` by constructing the `credentials` differently:

```py
from google.oauth2 import service_account
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(key_file, scopes=scopes)
delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject('admin@my.domain'). # <- I need this
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=delegated_credentials)
```

But this requires the creation of a secret key, which I'd like to avoid.

Is there a way to pass the subject in the first code example above ?

Comment: Can you clarify why you want to avoid creating a secret key?

Comment: It seems discouraged by Google, eg. [here: "Use service account keys only if there is no viable alternative"](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/how-to-authenticate-service-accounts-to-help-keep-applications-secure). In my case, there seems to be an alternative, since I manage to get an access token for the service without any user-managed key. Only impersonation of another user by that service is missing (which it can do, if authenticated with key).

Comment: So you want to run an "attached" service account? Are you sure you are running this from a supported platform and have [attached](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts#binding-to-resources) it?

Comment: I've come across the concept of attaching a service account to a resource. Unfortunately in our current workflow, we create one service account per customer (we are multi-tenant). IIUC there can be only one service account attached to our App Engine instance.

Comment: I think this might be the answer to your question in that case - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55354070/how-to-assign-multiple-service-account-credentials-to-google-cloud-functions - i.e. the service account identifies the app engine instance, so you can't attach more than one to it.

Comment: That answer confirms the one-to-one attachment constraint yes. My problem would remain the same though: how do I get that attached service account to impersonate the user corresponding the inbox where I want to insert the email ?

Comment: In other words, why is it I can only find the `with_subject()` method on credentials obtained by passing user-managed keys in python ? If this method was exposed on other types of service account Credentials, I guess the matter would be solved.

Comment: Have you seen anywhere that this actually can be done? From what I can read it seems like to perform domain-wide delegation you need the `Key` whether its attached or not - "A service account key lets an application authenticate as a service account, similar to how a user might authenticate with a username and password." that quote is from your link above, and https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority - its part of the required steps here and in other quickstarts for instance in the directory API.

Comment: Right, I'm totally prepared to accept that this can't be done. Just couldn't see it written down explicitly anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## AFAIK this is not possible

<sup>*Would be happy to be proved wrong on this!*</sup>

I place this as a disclaimer because you are right, it does not explicitly deny the possibility. Its not generally a requirement for documentation to explicitly express everything you can *not* do with it, though I do see the potential for confusion here so it might be worth "Sending Feedback" to the documentation page.

### What the instructions say

> #### Preparing to make an authorized API call
>
> *After you obtain the client email address and private key from the API Console ...*
>
> [*source*](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#python)

In no place does it say "this is an optional step". This is also true in other places like the [Directory API instructions on domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation), or the [Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/delegation)

### The Recommendation to not use Keys

The following is from the article you linked:

> #### Use service account keys only if there is no viable alternative
>
> *A service account key lets an application authenticate as a service
> account, similar to how a user might authenticate with a username and
> password.*
>
> [*source*](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/how-to-authenticate-service-accounts-to-help-keep-applications-secure)

When you attach a service account, for example to an App Engine instance, the instance is like the user and the service account is its user account. It serves as a sort of identity for the instance. More info on that on this other [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55354070/how-to-assign-multiple-service-account-credentials-to-google-cloud-functions).

So the only way for a service account to *act as-if it were* another account, ***is with a key***. Likewise the only way for a user to act as-if it were a service account is with a key. Therefore, if you are trying to enable domain-wide delegation, which presupposes that you want to have a service account act *as-if* it were other accounts, **having a key is essential**, whether the service account is attached to an App Engine instance or not.

Granted, its not mentioned explicitly that you can *not* achieve this without a key. Though it doesn't mention that you **can** either. From the tests that I have run, I have run into similar results as yours, so it would seem that you just can't. As mentioned in the disclaimer, I would be happy to be proved wrong, however, I suspect that it would be due to a vulnerability, not intended behavior.

You haven't mentioned why you need domain-wide delegation of authority, so you may want to evaluate if you really need it. Usually all that is needed is the OAuth flow, in which an app acts *oh-behalf* of a user, not *as-if* it were the user.

#### References

- [Access to Google APIs with Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#python)
- [How to Authenticate Service Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/how-to-authenticate-service-accounts-to-help-keep-applications-secure)
- [Directory API instructions on domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)
- [Reports API instructions on domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/delegation)
- ["How to assign multiple service accounts to cloud functions" (you can't)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55354070/how-to-assign-multiple-service-account-credentials-to-google-cloud-functions).

Comment: Thank you for your research, I will accept this answer as there is no other challenger. As to why I need domain-wide delegation, I work for a phishing simulation company, and as part of our service we write emails in mailboxes of different companies (different Google Workspaces). Which brings [its own set of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61823359/777285) 